# Is there any reason why no error found in calling navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia

Tags: webrtc, es6-promise, getusermedia

I'm writing Webrtc chrome desktop app by accessing 2 camera simultaneously using latest Chrome Windows version.

Accessing camera list by navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices() is ok but accessing these device by their specific id using navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia not work.

**It only occurs sometimes.** But no error in the catch.

So, I tried navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia is really exists or not.

if (navigator && navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
}

Yes, it was.

Just not getting any log info in calling navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()

```
getVideoSources_ = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if (typeof navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices === 'undefined') {
            alert('Your browser does not support navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices, aborting.');
            reject(Error("Your browser does not support navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices, aborting."));
            return;
        }

        requestVideoSetTimeout = 500;
        navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then((devices) => {

            // get the list first by sorting mibunsho camera in first place
            for (var i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
                log("devices[i]", JSON.stringify(devices[i]));
                log("devices[i].label", devices[i].label);
                if (devices[i].kind === 'videoinput' && devices[i].deviceId && devices[i].label) {
                    if (devices[i].label.indexOf("USB_Camera") > -1) {
                        deviceList[1] = devices[i];
                    } else {
                        deviceList[0] = devices[i];
                    }
                }
            }

            // request video by sorted plan
            for (var i = 0; i < deviceList.length; i++) {
                requestVideo_(deviceList[i].deviceId, deviceList[i].label, resolve, reject);
                requestVideoSetTimeout = 1000; // change requestVideoSetTimeout for next video request
            }
        }).catch((err) => {
            log("getVideoSources_:" + err.name + ": " + err.message);
            reject(Error("getVideoSources_ catch error"));
        });
    });
}
getVideoSources_().then(function(result) {
    ....
}).catch(function(err) {
    ....
});

function requestVideo_(id, label, resolve, reject) {
    if (navigator && navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        log("navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia found!");

        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            video: {
                deviceId: {exact: id},
                width: 640,
                height: 480,
                frameRate: {
                    ideal: 20,
                    max: 20
                }
            },
            audio: false}).then(
            (stream) => {
                log("***requestVideo_", id);
                log("***requestVideo_", label);
                log("***requestVideo_", stream);
          // USB_Camera is face camera
          if (label.indexOf("USB_Camera") > -1) {
            log("***requestVideo_001");
            myStream2 = stream;
            log("***requestVideo_myStream2", myStream2);
          } else {
            log("***requestVideo_002");
            myStream = stream;
            log("***requestVideo_myStream", myStream);
            getUserMediaOkCallback_(myStream, label);
          }
          resolve("###Video Stream got###");

          stream.getVideoTracks()[0].addEventListener('ended', function(){
            log("***Camera ended event fired. " + id + " " + label);
            endedDevice[id] = label;
          });
      },
      getUserMediaFailedCallback_
      ).catch((error) => {
        log('requestVideo_: ' + error.name);
        reject(Error("requestVideo_ catch error" + error.name));
      });
    }
}

function getUserMediaFailedCallback_(error) {
    log("getUserMediaFailedCallback_ error:", error.name);
    alert('User media request denied with error: ' + error.name);
}
```

Comment: Where do you define `i`, `resolve`, `reject`, `log`? There are ReferenceError in your catch block too, so for us it's normal it won't log anything. And assuming all these are declared somewhere, if `i` is an integer, but the device at index `i` is not a videoinput, then your code won't do anything.

Comment: I'm sorry, for the sake of simplicity I just copied some of my working code, now I edited the code again. Yes some variables like `log` is defined in somewhere. Thank you.

Comment: A promise can be resolved only once. Here you are passing both `resolve` and `reject` to `requestVideo_` in a loop.

Comment: Thank you. It could be a problem why there is no log sometimes. I will fix that first.

Comment: @Kaiido is right. This is the [promise constructor anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). In short: Don't write code inside promise constructors. Don't pass `resolve` and `reject` functions down. Instead, let functions return promises to you, and return them all so they form a chain.

Answer (score 3):

@Kaiido is right, `resolve` is called in a for-loop here, which is all over the place, and before all the code has finished. Any error after this point is basically lost.

This is the [promise constructor anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). In short: Don't write app code inside promise constructors. Don't pass `resolve` and `reject` functions down. Instead, let functions return promises up to you, and add all app code in `then` callbacks on them. Then return all promises so they form a single chain. Only then do errors propagate correctly.

See [Using promises on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Error_propagation) for more.